# Cron running on multiple server instance

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have a cron (deployed on multiple servers) in spring boot in which i want to get "n" records from a table* based on timestamp column.
And will update the is_proccessed field to true once these are processed.

Approach 1:

I have thought of using a SP in oracle which i will use "skip Locked" feature which will lock the records and will update is_processed field to true.

But in the above approach if there are 10000 records in single run then the update query will be taking time to update these record.

Approach 2:

I also thought of redisson lock, but in this if one cron gets the lock others will skip, which i don't want.

---

Is There any other approach by which all the n cron instance should get different records from DB every time the cron runs?

i.e Also, i want my code to scale properly.

PS:*instead of table, the data can be stored and retrieved from cache as well like aerospike or any other way(DB or kafka etc) to store and get data based on timestamp which suits the above case.

Answer (score 0):

This is so called a *distributed processing*.

Cron is good for executing limited latency tasks such as sql scripts but they're not scalable and weren't designed for these purposes. If you scale cron tasks it will cause a race condition since the schedule is would be the same across the instances.

In the practice, there's a number of common ways:

- Cron jobs in the [Leader Election](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leader_election) style. It means only one instance in a cluster is responsible for the task execution at time. Good thing for periodic tasks such as maintenance scripts but those are not suitable for the workload processing. See Kubernetes [CronJobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/)
- Concurrent workers. This is preferred way for the small and medium sized projects. You might want to poll some resource in order to *reserve* some data in a fixed interval instead of a cron since not all the workers will trigger in the same time. Then you can process the data read in the concurrent manner. The access to such resources must be synchronized in order to avoid duplicate reads. This is just like how [Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/) works.
- Distributed queue. There're many implementations exist including [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/), [Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/) etc. As you published the workload it is ready for the concurrent processing and the scalability is then easily achieved. This is the most expensive and common seen approach for the enterprise level software.